I'm trying to use list comprehension to create an addition function, but I'm encountering an error
Here's the code I'm using:
# Function to calculate the sum of digits in a number
def add_sum(a):
    return sum([int(i) for i in str(a)])

# Call the function with the number
result = add_sum(541646)
print(result)

I was trying to write a function for addition of numbers converting from string to integers colab throwing me value error
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8a8898029a4d> in <cell line: 6>()
      4 
      5 # Call the function with the number
----> 6 result = add_sum(541646)
      7 
      8 # Print the result

2 frames
<ipython-input-1-e66acdf936c5> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 def sum(a):
----> 2   return sum([int(i) for i in str(a)])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['


I cannot reproduce. Can you [edit] and add more information?

In the error output, I see the line def sum(a): -- this is redefining the builtin sum function and causing the error.
The code you pasted works.
(If you are NOT redefining sum() anywhere... then please provide more details on how you are running your code and if there is any additional code.)
